# file checking function will always "ignore" leading slash

Tags: php, file, operating-system

This question should be rather simple....... To reproduce the scenario, I have this structure set up:

```
Root
 |----/test/abc.txt
 |----index.php
```

index.php

```
$root = __DIR__;

echo is_file($root . "/test/abc.txt") ? "true" : "false";
echo is_file($root . "//test/abc.txt") ? "true" : "false";
echo is_file($root . "///test/abc.txt") ? "true" : "false";

echo is_dir($root . "/test") ? "true" : "false";
echo is_dir($root . "//test") ? "true" : "false";
echo is_dir($root . "///test") ? "true" : "false";

echo file_exists($root . "/test") ? "true" : "false";
echo file_exists($root . "//test") ? "true" : "false";
echo file_exists($root . "///test") ? "true" : "false";
```

**Output:** `is_file()`

```
true
true
true
```

**Output:** `is_dir()`

```
true
true
true
```

**Output:** `file_exists()`

```
true
true
true
```

The leading slash seems to be "ignored" and regardless it can still find the file location. I thought a slash indicates a folder directory, but I seem to be wrong. what is happening here??

This might be an environment setting problem, but I don't have a linux set up to test yet.

My current environment is under windows OS, XAMPP.

**Update:**

This also seem to apply to `is_dir()` and `file_exists()` function.

Comment: It is only the MS-Windows operating system that uses a black slash ( \ ) as a directory boundary marker. Other operating systems (Linux, Unix, MacOS) use a forward slash (`/`). That is why generally in "the internet" and "the web" (whatever that actually means) the forward slash is what is agreed upon. Languages like PHP try to accept both and make sense of it. But if in doubt go with forward slashes. So to me the output of your test script does make sense in all points. Double slashes are treated like single slashes, a trailing slash indicates a directory, not a file.

Comment: @arkascha sorry I have a typo, the backslash should be "forward slash" since I was using forward slash in the code -_-"", but you said `Double slashes are treated like single slashes`, then technically hundred of forward slash wont be matter to the path that exist ??

Comment: There are interpreted as a single forward slash in a path argument, yes.

Comment: Same with `/./././`, since the single dot (`.`) stands for a directory itself.

Comment: Oh, btw, you may want to take a look at the `realpath()` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Comment: @arkascha thanks! I didn't know that, I am just trying to explore the file path behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since pretty much everything of value came out of the Unix world where the separator is the forward slash, many systems when ported to the windows environment will treat either slash as a separator.

And a trailing slash is acceptable only if what proceeded it is a directory.

Comment: Lol, I love the phrasing in "everything of value"... (though we all know that there are also some really annoying stupid things like the X architecture for example...)

Comment: Yes, some dumb stuff came out of it too.  For example, naming the syscall `creat()`  Seriously?  Would including that last `e` kill you?

Comment: Makefiles I can live with, except the sneaking suspicion that they influenced Python's idiotic "indentation == block" syntax.

Comment: Well, that is not idiotic at all, _if_ it is done in a consequent way, as in Python. It may be seen as unfamiliar. Issue with Makefiles is that it is part fish, part meat... Oh, and shouldn't it be "indentation === block" syntax?

Comment: We'll just have to agree to disagree on that :)